# How to handleRemove button in react functional component

Tags: reactjs

I made a delete button using a filter.
It's not going as well as I thought. Can I ask for advice?

the props that convey remove.
Info -> InputList (map) -> InputInfo

`info.js`

```
const [information, setInformation] = useState([]);

  const handleCreate = data => {
    setInformation(
      information.concat({
        ...data,
        id: id++,
      })
    );
  };

  const handleRemove = id => {
    setInformation(information.filter(user => user.id !== id));
    console.log('remove>>>>', information);
  };

  return(
  <Input onCreate={handleCreate} />
  <InputList data={information} onRemove={handleRemove} />
  )
```

---

`InputList`

```
const InputList = ({ data, onRemove }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(info => {
        return <InputInfo key={info.id} info={info} onRemove={onRemove} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

`InputInfo`

```
const InputInfo = ({ info, onRemove, id }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <Text>name: {info.name}</Text>
        <Text>phone : {info.phone}</Text>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => onRemove(id)}>remove</button>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are not passing `id` to the InputInfo component, so it is undefined for sure. Maybe you want to call onRemove with `info.id` instead (`onRemove(info.id)`).

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I fixed it like this and it went my way.
`<button onClick={() => onRemove(info.id)}>remove</button>`